# How to arrange response from same endpoint based on the authorization?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, backend

I am using express for endpoints, and PostgreSQL for the database. In the app, there are multiple user types, called user and issuer. Issuers are able to create certificates and issue them to users. I am having trouble returning different responses for the same endpoint based on the user role.

For instance I have `getCreatedCertificates` endpoint, which brings certificates created by an issuer. These certificates are public, meaning that any user can also see these created certificates inside the issuer's profile. But they should see it with less detailed information compared to what the creator of the certificate is seeing. They are technically both retrieving the same thing, which is certificates created by that issuer, but issuer him/herself should be able to access much more detailed information.

I don't think separating this into another endpoint is a good solution, they are almost  same with the exception of few different select columns. I also don't want to check the user role every time within a controller function, this brings too much boilerplate code on every one of the endpoints. I think middleware function is the way to go but I am unable imagine how that middleware function would efficiently and clearly know the return values for each GET endpoints and feed them into the controller function. How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: In the middleware function get the user details by the params you are getting through request. Here you can check the type of user. And attach this to the request object. Like req.userRole = role. And you can access this in the actual route by using the same. Here project the data according to the user type.

Comment: So you are suggesting extracting user type in middleware function, and then in controller function by checking this user type, return the relevant columns. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes Exactly....